# Is <profileable> safe in the production build?

Tags: android, performance, android-manifest, macrobenchmark

For using [macrobenchmark](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/benchmarking/macrobenchmark-overview), we need to add `<profileable>` to AndroidManifest.

```xml
<profileable
    android:shell="true"
    tools:targetApi="q" />
```

Is it safe to include `<profileable>` in the production build?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is considered [safe](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/profileable-element). It exposes only limited amount of information that are either obfuscated or lacking symbols in the release build. Some of the Google apps are using it in production.

Answer (score 2):

Why not merge this manifest node with the `debug` source-set?
One also could remove it from the `release` source-set, same effect.
This might not answer the question, but it makes it irrelevant.

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense. I will merge the manifest in my project. But, I want to know it. If it has any problem, I will share it with my colleagues.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, in particular what it does or if it even still works with `debuggable="false"`... but it's generally a good practice to keep all debug-mode related things strictly apart from the release build. Alike in this case, when not being certain about it - it doesn't matter.